# Using multer and stream to save file in google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, stream, google-cloud-storage, buffer, multer

I'm doing my best to upload a file **directly to google cloud storage**, using koa.js and multer.
I carefully read through the other SO questions, google api documentation and several tutorials and was able to upload the file successfully, but I have a question.

From what I understand the sequence I made with my code is: 
*FILE >>> Upload to backend (memorystorage) >>> upload to Google Cloud Storage.*

I would like the file to start uploading to google "directly", without first being fully read by the backend and loaded into memory.

I tried and wrote two different approaches (see code below) but in my opinion neither of them works as I would like, and having to upload even large files I don't want to risk creating performance problems for the server during uploads.

Can you help me better understand how to do it and also explain **the concrete difference of the two codes I wrote**?

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import KoaRouter from '@koa/router';
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';
import multer from '@koa/multer';

const kr = new KoaRouter();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
},

kr.post('/upload', multer.single('uploadedFile'), async (ctx, next) => {

  const fileToUpload = ctx.request.file.buffer

  // google cloud storage bucket and file (omitting auth part)
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('testbucket');
  const newFile = bucket.file('testfile');

  // SOLUTION A: Create a pass through stream
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`File upload START: `, new Date());
    const passthroughStream = new Stream.PassThrough();
    passthroughStream.write(fileToUpload);
    passthroughStream.end();
    passthroughStream
      .pipe(newFile.createWriteStream({ resumable: false, gzip: true, contentType: fileMimeType }))
      .on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`File upload END: `, new Date());
        resolve(true);
      });
  });

  // SOLUTION B: Create a readable stream
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`File upload START: `, new Date());
    const stream = Readable.from(fileToUpload);
    stream
      .pipe(newFile.createWriteStream({ resumable: false, gzip: true, contentType: fileMimeType }))
      .on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`File upload END: `, new Date());
        resolve(true);
      });
  });

  console.log(`File successfully uploaded`);
})
```